# Host cannot ping Minikube node

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have ubuntu 16.04 and followed the official documentation to install kubectl (v1.7.2) and minikube(v0.21.0) on my machine (with virtualbox).

I've got minikube running in my virtual box, and I can also do all the minikube command line operations.But kubectl does not work as expected.

By running `kubectl cluster-info`, it shows 

`Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.99.100:8443
To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.`

I tried to ping 192.168.99.100 on my host, it shows packet filtered:

`PING 192.168.99.100 (192.168.99.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 64.46.11.65 icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
From 64.46.11.65 icmp_seq=2 Packet filtered`

By running `kubectl get pod`, it shows

`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: no route to host`

note:  My UFW is disabled; I can ssh into minikube and ping outside world and my host.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

it's all due to ip mismatching, look I was facing the same problem but I checked that on my VM on which I was running Minikube was using 'NAT' adaptor and the Linux OS from which I was pinging it was using 'Bridged Adaptor', so I just changed the 'Bridged' of linux to 'NAT'
and boom! it worked. I can ping and do ssh now.

You can try this!!

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to check your routes using the `route` command. Maybe there are conflicts with the IP minikube is using and the rest of your network. Could you confirm that the route to your minikube VM is using the correct virtual interface?

Comment: I don't see 192.168.99.xxx in my route table. how to add it?